# Raspberry3. Correct for perspective

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi3

I'm new here, and i have googled my problem, but I find it hard to state it in simple words.

I have a gopigo 3 kit with a Raspberry Pi Camera Module. The camera is mounted at a 45 degree angle. I would like to transform the image in a way that makes it like it's taken from above. I can't find any simple way to do this. Any suggestions would be greatly appretiated. :)

Comment: I don't think this is really the correct place for this.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.  Maybe The [Photo](https://photo.stackexchange.com) StackExchange site would be a better place for this.

Comment: This is an image manipulation question, not specifically a programming one. Sorry Jon.

Comment: Your question is not super clear. Maybe search for  "bird eye view transformation", if this is what you need I would suggest trying to use OpenCV in Python to do that.